# MongoDB Aggregate lookup in Go (mgo.v2)

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mgo

I'm trying to implement `$lookup` functionality in one of my mongoDB queries in go (golang) using the [mgo](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2) package.

Below are my collections:

**folders:**

```
"_id"    : ObjectId("22222222222222"),
"name"   : "Media",
"level"  : 1,
"userIDs": [ObjectId("4444444444444")]
```

**documents:**

```
"_id"      : ObjectId("11111111111111"),
"title"    : "Media Management",
"body"     : BinData(0,"PvQ6z2NBm4265duo/e2XsYxA5bXKo="),
"level"    : 1,
"folderID" : ObjectId("22222222222222"), // Foreign Key/Field
"userIDs"  : [ObjectId("44444444444444")]
```

Below is the query I've written that successfully runs on the shell:

```
var query = [
{ 
  "$lookup": {
    "from":         "documents",
    "localField":   "_id",
    "foreignField": "folderID",
    "as":           "documents",
  }
}
 ,{
   "$match": {
      "userIDs": ObjectId("userIdHere"), // filder by a userID
      "level": {$gte: 0},                // filter by a folder level
    },
  }
];

db.folders.aggregate(query).pretty().shellPrint();
```

If I run this script on the shell, I get the desired result. Basically, the `folder` collection is returned to me containing the full relevant `documents` that were linked through the `$lookup`. I'm not including it here because this question already seems too long.

I've tried to translate this query into something that *mgo* would be able to parse and execute. Here it is below in go code:

```
query := bson.M{
  "$lookup": bson.M{ // lookup the documents table here
  "from":         "documents",
  "localField":   "_id",
  "foreignField": "folderID",
  "as":           "documents",
},
  "$match": bson.M{
    "level":   bson.M{"$gte": user.Level}, // filter by level
    "userIDs": user.ID,                    // filter by user
  },
}

pipe := collection.Pipe(query) // querying the "folders" collection
err := pipe.All(&result)
```

I always get the same error: **wrong type for field (pipeline) 3 != 4**

If I understand correctly, it's because it can't properly parse the result back into the $result object. I've done everything I can to ensure the struct has the exact structure that is required. I've also tried to pass in a genereric `[]interface{}` and an empty `bson.M{}` objects. Still receive the same error.

Below is my Folders struct:

```
type Folder struct {
  ID        bson.ObjectId   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  Name      string          `json:"name"`
  Level     int             `json:"level"`
  UserIDs   []bson.ObjectId `json:"userIDs" bson:"userIDs"`
  Users     []User          `json:"-" bson:"-"` // doesn't get stored in the database
  Documents []Document      `json:"-" bson:"-"` // doesn't get stored in the database
}
```

I've also removed the `$match` clause to see if I could get anything at all back from that `$lookup` query. But I still get the same error.

Perhaps the mgo package doesn't support `$lookup`? If so, would there be another way? **Perhaps I could send the raw query text to mongo and receive the raw response and parse it myself?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution!

The trick was to create the query in a slice (`[]bson.M`) and change the structure of the query a bit:

```
query := []bson.M{{
  "$lookup": bson.M{ // lookup the documents table here
    "from":         "documents",
    "localField":   "_id",
    "foreignField": "folderID",
    "as":           "documents",
  }},
  {"$match": bson.M{
    "level": bson.M{"$lte": user.Level},
    "userIDs": user.ID,
}}}

pipe := collection.Pipe(query)
err := pipe.All(&folders)
```

I found a clue in [mgo's Pipe function docs](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Pipe). Also, I had to change the tags for the `Documents` field in my `Folders` struct for mgo to pupolate that field:

```
type Folder struct {
  ID        bson.ObjectId   `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
  Name      string          `json:"name"`
  Level     int             `json:"level"`
  UserIDs   []bson.ObjectId `json:"userIDs" bson:"userIDs"`
  Users     []User          `json:"-" bson:"-"` // doesn't get stored in the database
  Documents []Document      // `json:"-" bson:"-" Removed this so that mgo can unmarshal
                            // the documents correctly
}
```

Now I just have to figure out a way to not store the `Documents` field in the database when I save a `Folder`.